# Azure Sql DataWareHouse API

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

Is there a REST API for Azure Sql Datawarehouse? Like API for creating server, table etc.

I don't see anything in the documentation https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-overview-what-is/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of the Rest APIs that are supported for SQLDB are also supported for SQLDW. See here for reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163685.aspx

This should also have Rest APIs for create database/server which you are looking for. You just need to make sure you enter in the correct params (which should be listed in the link above)

Examples -
Edition: DataWarehouse
ServiceLevelObject: DW400
Version: V12

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

No, the idea is that you submit SQL commands to it, similar to how you submit commands to any relational database. I guess it's very feasible to create a set of wrappers, but I doubt Microsoft will prioritise creating such a thing.

Comment: I was looking for a Redshift like API for Azure SQL datawarehouse.

Comment: Ok. But it's not Redshift. It's a relational database with the parallel paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-manage-compute-rest-api/

Comment: That doesn't do things like create tables - it only changes settings that are with Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the available APIs, You can not do DML and DDL operations using APIs. You have to create a Wrapper for that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/